# How to move the PLACEHOLDER text to the top

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I have a little problem, a bit stupid I guess, but couldn't figure it out.

In my HTML Form code, the input ("text") where the user will write their message, I have put a placeholder, as you see in the image:

[PLACEHOLDER IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA1nr.png)

I would like the placeholder to be at the top. How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Regards and sorry for my English. Spanish guy over here ;)

---

```
THE HTML CODE

<form>
<input type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message...">
</form>

THE CSS CODE

#message{
 width:450px;
 height:240px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin-top:20px;
 background-color:transparent;
 color:white;
 border:1px solid white;
}
```

EDIT:

DONE.

I just changed the "input type="text"" to "textarea" and added some cols and rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a **textarea** instead of an **input**, try that! and if you want to make it bigger just add **cols="x"** and **rows="x**" atributes on the textarea tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a textarea within jsfiddle.

```
<textarea id="message" rows="8" cols="50" placeholder="Your message here"></textarea>
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/cdLNL/

Comment: Actually did that! Thanks!