# How to position placeholder text inside a input?

Tags: input, user-input, textinput, html-input

I have a text input

[image]

I want to place it as in this.

[image]

I'm requesting help from community for this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide the source code you've written to achieve this?

Comment: I recommend [using `<textarea>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156498/how-to-move-the-placeholder-text-to-the-top) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose if you want to align placeholder text to center,then following piece of code will be used.

```
<style>
input[type="text"]:: placeholder
{   
 text-align: center;
}
</style>
```